# Matrices and Rank with an unknown variable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, matrix-rank

This is a question about finding the rank of a matrix where one of the elements is an unknown variable.

I saw this online a few days ago and have been struggling to figure out how I find the rank of this matrix for all values of $a$:
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1 & 1 & 4\\
a & 4 & 10 & 1\\
1 & 7 & 17 & 3\\
2 & 2 & 4 & 3\\
\end{pmatrix}

I know that the rank of a matrix can be deduced by figuring out how many independent column (or row) vectors the matrix has. Alternatively, the row-echelon-form of the matrix can be found and observed to see how many non-zero rows the $rref$ has, but the unknown variable is confusing me on doing both.

What is the best way to find the $rref$ or deduce independent row (or column) vectors? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The unknown variable $a$ should not "confuse" you for computing the row-echelon-form. Just do the operations on $a$. If you multiply the row $(a,4,10,1)$ by two, then just do $(2a,8,20,2)$ and so on. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1954656/rank-of-matrix-with-variable), for example.

Comment: Small hint - what happens for $a=0$?

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean, we can express elements which involve variable $a$ as just an operation(s) of the variable and observe what happens for different values of $a$. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the first step:

Rearranging some of the rows, we have
$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc} 1&7&17&3 \\ 2&2&4&3 \\ 3&1&1&4 \\ a&4&10&1 \end{array} \right].$$

Then performing the row operations $R_2 \to R_2 - 2R_1$, $R_3 \to R_3 - 3R_1$ and $R_4 \to R_4 - aR_1$, we have
$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc} 1&7&17&3 \\ 0&-12&-30&-3 \\ 0&-20&-50&-5 \\ 0&4-7a&10-17a&1-3a \end{array} \right].$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: i see that you express the transformations as operations on the variable $a$ where appropriate. Thats a helpful way of looking at it, thank you! I think I could see how you would do the rest of it and get it to $rref$